# How to put a image Sticker in a square box?

Tags: java, android

I am using this library in my project [StickerView](https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView)

In this library, we can give position to a sticker added e.g.

```
stickerview.addSticker(drawable, position)
```

But this gives position to only one side.. I want to position the stickerview in 4 bounds i-e in a square...

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post screenshot?

Comment: get the code and edit

Comment: Hello Ali, welcome to Stackoverflow. You only need two positions combinations to properly align your stickerview. Try something like this stickerView.addSticker(new DrawableSticker(drawable1), Sticker.Position.BOTTOM | Sticker.Position.RIGHT);

Comment: @Nikhil i tried that but that's not working